# Struts2: unclear syntax of input of type submit

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm looking at someone's code and I found the following line of html/struts code on a .jsp file:

```
<input type="submit" name="action:datadefinitionsAddSample" id="btnAddSample"/>
```

I don't understand the name="action:" part. Is this the syntax for triggering an action when the button is pressed? I thought the correct syntax for doing that was:

```
<input type="submit" action="datadefinitionsAddSample" id="btnAddSample"/>
```

So, which syntax is correct, or if both are, what do they really do?

Just for reference, this is the relevant part of the struts.xml file:

```
<action name="datadefinitionsAddSample" class="DataDefinitionsCRUD" method="addSample">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">datadefinitionsform</param>
        <param name="id">${dataDefinition.id}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Comment: I prefer the first, though. It is more clear, and prevents errors.

Comment: `<input action="..."/>` is invalid, there is nothing like that, you can use `formaction` attribute instead, check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp

Comment: To expand on what Lukasz said: HTML `<input>` tags don't *have* an `action` attribute, forms do. Using `action:` as part of the field name triggers Struts 2 functionality.